# Add an external link using iText to an existing pdf file

Tags: java, itext

The scenario is I have an existing pdf file and i need to search and replace a string of text and the new text should now become a hyper link, like so[image: before and final state of the pdf file]

before the file and the result that i want

Comment: What have you done so far, where is your code ?

Comment: Yes, you need to show what you've done, because you are bundling 2 or 3 separate questions in one single sentence.

Comment: I don't have anything code of yet because I don't know where to begin, basically what I want to achieve is to turn a string of text in a pdf file into a hyperlink